# Unexpected zero-byte message received on ZMQ-SUB socket

Tags: multicast, zeromq

I am trying to exchange messages between 4 processes using multicasting [epgm: loopback interface].

All 4 processes belong to same group. Two processes send data and the other two receive this data. In both subscribing processes I am receiving one zero byte message (in between the actual publisher messages). There are no processes sending empty message on the port as far as I know.

I am not able to figure out why zero byte message is received. Any help is much appreciated.

Note: If I have only one publisher process then I don’t receive any zero byte message in the subscriber processes.

Comment: can you post some actual code that reproduces the issue?